# Square root of a matrix as it relates to the identity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

Prove that for any $2×2$ matrix $M$ which is “sufficiently close” to the identity matrix, there exists a matrix A such that $A^2 = M$, and that this matrix A is unique if $A$ isrequired to be “sufficiently close” to the identity matrix. In your proof, you should also carefully define what it means for two matrices to be “sufficiently close.” 
(Hint: Use the Implicit Function Theorem or the Inverse Function Theorem. Notice
that a 2 × 2 matrix can be thought of as a vector in $\mathbb{R}
^4$.

I don't understand what is meant by sufficiently close.  I'm working in the book Advanced Calculus by Fitzpatrick.  It seems like the idea behind this question is asking for a neighborhood near enough so that a vector valued function is a bijection in that neighborhood.  Can someone give me the idea of how to start this proof and if there is some obscure detail I might need, perhaps a hint?

Comment: *Sufficiently close* here means that there is some open neighborhood $U$ of $I_2 \in M(2, \Bbb R)$ (for which the map $A \mapsto A^2$ is injective).

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Consider the function $A \mapsto A^2$ on $2 \times 2$ matrices.